# Docker returns this page isn't working after building it

Tags: docker, nginx

So I am trying setup docker in my app. This is what currently I have docer-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_app
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.docker/php/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app_network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_nginx
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./.:/usr/src/app
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - app_network

  db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    image: mysql:latest
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}-root
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    networks:
      - app_network

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Composer
ENV COMPOSER_VERSION 2.0.12

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=$COMPOSER_VERSION

# Install nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libzip-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        zip \
        nodejs \
        yarn \
        default-mysql-client \
    && apt-get clean \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        exif \
        gd \
        opcache \
        pdo_mysql \
        pcntl \
        zip \
        bcmath \
        intl \
        soap \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /usr/src/app

# Change current user to www
USER www

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /usr/src/app/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

But when I use `docker-compose up` and everything builds up after long time. I go to `localhost:80` I get this [image]

Would appreciate some help why this could be happening. I am completely new with docker, nginx.

Comment: Hi ! Would you provide us the relevant part of the `nginx` error log, if any ?

Comment: you don't need the EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"] in your Dockerfile and in your docker-compose's nginx block are you sure that you want to mount `- ./.:/usr/src/app` the dot